# How to plot misclassified samples in shap?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, plot, shap

I have a dataset of genes scored between 0 to 1 of the likelihood of causing disease (genes scored at 1 are known to cause disease, and a gene scored at say 0.74 is probable to cause disease). I am trying to build a machine learning model to predict that disease score for new genes in regression classification.

I want to look at a shap decision plot for the genes which are known disease genes but are being scored low (e.g. genes that are scored 1 but my model is scoring less than 0.8). I am struggling to group these genes together to plot.

My data looks like:

```
X:
Index   Feature1  Feature2   ... FeatureN
Gene1     1           0.2          10
Gene2     1           0.1          7
Gene3     0           0.3          10
#index is actually the index and not a column

Y:
Score
1
0.6
0.4
```

I run an xgboost regressor with nested cross validation and look at the MSE, predicted r2, and plot the observed vs expected values. I can see in the observed vs expected plot that the genes scored 1 in Y have many low scores predicted by the model, I want to understand why the model is doing this with using shap. I cannot give example data unfortunately.

I am trying to adapt example shap code given for label classification:

```
import shap

xgbr = xgboost.XGBRegressor()
xgbr.fit(X_train, Y_train)

select = range(8) #I have 8 features after feature selection with BorutaShap
features = X.iloc[select]
features_display = X.loc[features.index]

explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(xgbr)
expected_value = explainer.expected_value

#Example code from https://slundberg.github.io/shap/notebooks/plots/decision_plot.html: 

y_pred = xgbr.predict(X) 
y_pred = (shap_values.sum(1) + expected_value) > 0
misclassified = y_pred != y_test[select]
shap.decision_plot(expected_value, shap_values, features_display, link='logit', highlight=misclassified)
```

How do I select `y_pred` so it is predictions/genes that were meant to be 1 but were actually lower than 0.8 (or any low number)?

edit: in response to the given answer I have tried:

```
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(xgbr)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_test)

y_pred = xgbr.predict(X_test)
m = (y_pred <= 0.5) & (Y_test == 1)

shap.initjs()
shap.decision_plot(explainer.expected_value, shap_values,  X_test[m],  return_objects=True)
```

This runs but `m` is a length of 171 (the entire number of rows in my Y_test data) and the plot then plots all 171 it looks like - and I know from looking at the data there should be only one gene that is <= 0.5 and but is actually scored at 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you mention *predict that disease score for new genes in regression classification*, what do you mean? The output seems to be binary, `0` or `1`, hence this is a binary classification problem. You should be using `xgboost`'s classifier instead. *Update*: Let's assume a regression problem though, as per the comments, to simulate your case. Though for the example bellow we should set `'objective':'multi:softmax'` to output the actual labels.

As per your question, it seems that what you're trying to do is to index the test set on those samples that where not correctly predicted, and analyse the *misleading* features, which makes a reasonable amount of sense.

Let's reproduce your problem with some sample dataset:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import shap
import xgboost

X,y = shap.datasets.iris()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)

model = xgboost.train(params={"learning_rate": 0.01}, 
                      dtrain=xgboost.DMatrix(X_train, label=y_train), 
                      num_boost_round =100)
```

A SHAP plot using the entire test set, is straight forward. For a `force_plot` for instance:

```
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_test)

shap.initjs()
shap.force_plot(explainer.expected_value, shap_values, X_test)
```

[image]

Now, if we want to do the same with the missclassified samples, we need to look at the output probabilities. Since the iris dataset has several classes, let's say we want to visuallize the `force_plot` for those samples that should've been classified as `2`, but we instead have an output value bellow `1.7`:

```
y_pred = model.predict(xgboost.DMatrix(X_test))
m = (y_pred <= 1.7) & (y_test == 2)
```

Now we lets use the mask to perform boolean indexing on the `X_test` set, and update the `shap_values`:

```
shap.initjs()
c= explainer.shap_values(X_test[m])
shap.force_plot(explainer.expected_value, shap_values, X_test[m])
```

[image]

This is telling us that it is the petal length and width that are mostly pushing the *regression* to a higher value. Hence they presumably are the variables that are playing a major part in the misclassification.

Similarly, for a `decision_plot`:

```
shap.decision_plot(explainer.expected_value, shap_values, 
                   X_test[m], feature_order='hclust', 
                   return_objects=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this, it's very helpful. Although I have not explained well enough that I have a regression where Y is any value between 0-1 so whilst 1 is a known disease gene 0.74 is a probable disease gene and 0.17 is an unlikely gene and so on. I've tried running your code with my data, it gives an error at the : ```IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).``` - do you know why I might be getting this? I will keep trying in the mean time

Comment: This looks like an indexing caused error. Make sure that your are creating the mask on `y_test` and `y_pred`, and then indexing `X_test` @DN1

Comment: The boolean mask has to have to correct dimensions. I defined it using `y_pred` and `y_test`, because they have the same shape. I can then use it to mask `X_test`, because it *also has the same shape* @DN1

Comment: Thank you for this, I've solved this error and everything runs, but ```m``` seems to give me all of my test data and not just the low scored genes I am looking for - I've updated my question with the details if it is possible for you to see if I've got something missing still - thank you for all your help too.

Comment: Yes. `m` has the same shape as `X_test`. Because it is used to mask it. `X_test[m]` however, will have as many values as `True`s there are in the mask @DN1

Comment: I think I've solved it, but I have a biology background so unsure - does ```shap_values``` also need to be  ```shap_values[m]``` ? For me this seems to plot as I expected it to when checking the data manually, but want to make sure I'm not doing something else unknown to me

Comment: No, for the shap values you only need to index usign the mask. Check the shapes of the arrays. If you do `explainer.shap_values(X_test[m]).shape` you'll get as many rows as `X_test[m]`. The shap values are already indexed. @DN1

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have your dataset, I can't check the code, but here some thoughts that may show you the direction.

It seem that you do not train you regressor. It should be line like

```
xgbr = xgboost.XGBRegressor()
xgbr.train(X, Y)
```

Now you can use `xgbr.predict(X)` ;)

You also need to train explainer:

```
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(xgbr)
with warnings.catch_warnings():
     warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
     sh = explainer.shap_values(X)
```

And now you can select values:

```
misclassified = (y_pred <= 0.7) & (Y == 1)
shap.decision_plot(expected_value, sh, features_display, link='logit', highlight=misclassified)
```

Before you use `shap` I suggest you check how good your regressor fits your data. So for this I suggest you take part of the data for test **without** using it in training. Then you can evaluate goodness of fit by calculating and comparing the MSE on test and training sets. The larger the difference, the worse your predictor performs.

Comment: Thank you for this, looking at what ```misclassified``` gives me from using your code it's a list of whether the rows are TRUE or FALSE for the statements, sending this into the decision_plot at least for me doesn't just plot the misclassified. Is there a way to select ```misclassified``` with getting the whole rows and not just the true/false if they match the conditions? Also sorry I will add more detail in my question, I look at the model with MSE and predicted r2 in nested cross-validation. I also plot the observed vs expected and it seems to do badly mostly with Y=1 gene predictions.